# C++/CLI Converting System::Object ^ to std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a listBox in Visual C++ 2008, and I want the first line convert to string. So first, I select the first line

```
listBox1->SetSelected( 0, true );
```

And afterwards, I want to convert it to string

```
string t = listBox1->SelectedItems[ 0 ];
```

Which results in an error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely look into using the [marshal_as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx) template method. It handles all the nasty conversions for you internally.